# Lua - attempt to call global 'contains' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, global

I'm interesting, if who know what is the problem of this code bellow. I always get this error:

''attempt to call global 'contains' (a nil value)''

Here is the code:

```
state1={10,11,20,21,22,23,24,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,69,72,73,74,85}
state3={78}
state4={1,2,3,4,5,6}

playerskin=initArray2(32,0)
wepskin=initArray2(32,0)

function getPlayerData(id,d)
if (d=="team") then
    if (player(id,"team")==1) then
        return "red"
    end
    if (player(id,"team")==2) then
        return "blu"
    end
end
if (d=="class") then
    return string.lower(tf2.classes.name[tf2.classes.class[id]])
end
end

function changeSkin(id,w)
if (contains(state1,w)) then
    if (playerskin[id]~=0) then
        freeimage(playerskin[id])
    end
    playerskin[id]=image("gfx/tf2/skins/"..getPlayerData(id,"team").."   /"..getPlayerData(id,"class").."/"..getPlayerData(id,"team").."_"..getPlayerData(id,"class").."_1.png",1,0,200+id)
end
if (contains(state3,w)) then
    if (playerskin[id]~=0) then
        freeimage(playerskin[id])
    end
    playerskin[id]=image("gfx/tf2/skins/"..getPlayerData(id,"team").."/"..getPlayerData(id,"class").."/"..getPlayerData(id,"team").."_"..getPlayerData(id,"class").."_3.png",1,0,200+id)
end
if (contains(state4,w)) then
    if (playerskin[id]~=0) then
        freeimage(playerskin[id])
    end
    playerskin[id]=image("gfx/tf2/skins/"..getPlayerData(id,"team").."/"..getPlayerData(id,"class").."/"..getPlayerData(id,"team").."_"..getPlayerData(id,"class").."_4.png",1,0,200+id)
end
if (hat[id]~=0 and tf2.classes.hatunlock[id][tf2.classes.class[id]]~=0) then
    freeimage(hat[id])
    hat[id]=image(crafts[tf2.classes.hatunlock[id] [tf2.classes.class[id]]].image,1,0,200+id)
end
end

--[[function changeWeaponSkin(id,w)
if (wepskin[id]~=0) then
    freeimage(wepskin[id])
end
wepskin[id]=image("gfx/tf2/skins/weapons/"..getPlayerData(id,"class").." /"..string.lower(tf2.classes.weaponnames[w])..".png",1,0,200+id)
end
]]

addhook("select","tf2.classes.images")
function tf2.classes.images(id,w)
if (player(id,"armor")~=206) then
    changeSkin(id,player(id,"weapontype"))
    --changeWeaponSkin(id,w)
end
end

addhook("spawn","tf2.classes.spawndebug")
function tf2.classes.spawndebug(id)
if (player(id,"armor")~=206) then
    changeSkin(id,player(id,"weapontype"))
    timer(10,"parse","lua changeSkin("..id..",player("..id..",\"weapontype \"))")
    if (tf2.classes.hatunlock[id][tf2.classes.class[id]]~=0) then
        timer(10,"parse","lua freeimage("..hat[id]..")")
        timer(10,"parse","lua   hat["..id.."]=image(crafts[tf2.classes.hatunlock["..id.."][tf2.classes.class["..id.."]]].image,1,0,200+"..id..")")
    else
        timer(10,"parse","lua freeimage("..hat[id]..")")
        timer(10,"parse","lua hat["..id.."]=0")
    end
end
end

addhook("attack2","tf2.classes.spycloak")
function tf2.classes.spycloak(id)
if (tf2.classes.class[id]==9 and player(id,"armor")==0) then
    if (playerskin[id]~=0) then
        freeimage(playerskin[id])
    end
    --[[
    if (wepskin[id]~=0) then
        freeimage(wepskin[id])
```

If you've the solution please help me.

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your have

```
if( contains(...) ) then
```

in your code segments. The function `contains` need to be defined for it to be called. The function definition is missing.

You can use something like this(if you want to find `w` inside the table):

```
function contains( tPassed, iValue )
    for _, v in pairs( tPassed ) do
        if tonumber(v) == tonumber(iValue) then
            return true
        end
    end
    return nil
end
```

Comment: Thanks hjpotter92! I added this code you wrote in the first lines before code and it's working now! Thanks again:)